# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javafx

I am a beginner in JavaFX and trying to run JavaFX in Eclipse on Ubuntu.

I have openjfx installed on my pc, but it is giving the error

> JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.

I have searched a lot but not got any solution.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install openjfx`

Comment: You are using Java 10 which still contains JavaFX, what is under "jfxrt"? Is your project a module? What is the build configuration?

Comment: @guleryuz Yes i have tried this

Comment: @user1803551 jfxrt contains jfxrt.jar file

Comment: what happens when you add jfxrt.jar to your project's classpath (right click on project > build path > configure build path > java build path > libraries > add external jar >  jfxrt.jar)

Comment: Nothing happens ,when i run the projects error shows in console

Comment: ok, what happens when you add `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` in your `eclipse.ini` as described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9), don't forget to restart your eclipse after change to `eclipse.ini`

Comment: It is showing
Project 'HelloWorld' is missing required library: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar'

Comment: You did not answer my other questions.

Comment: Ok, can you please remove jxfrt.jar from build path which you added in the previous step and retry

Comment: @guleryuz for now i have installed netbeans but i will do it later thank you for your help!!

Comment: Try this (I got the same error, this worked for me): Right click on the Java file -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Click on 'Arguments' Tab -> VM argumments: -> Provide this value `--module-path /<path>/javafx-sdk-11/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls`

Answer (score 6):

Try simply creating a launcher.
For your App, it should look something like this:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;

public class MainLaunch {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

(you can leave the old main Method unused in your App for the time-being)
This worked for me with JDK 13 & JavaFX 13 & Eclipse 2019-12 under Ubuntu.
(I created the Project using "new/Maven Project/Simple Project" and then just added JavaFX, Logging & other stuff as dependencies in pom.xml, which all landed on the Classpath. Only the JDK was on the Modulepath)
No need to bother about Java Modules.

If that works, you can take time to learn about Java Modularisation another day...

Comment: Great answer, but why do I have to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm one of those (the many) who's deferred learning about Java Modularisation until another day!  But I did find the following.: https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error/

Comment: @BentheCoder Part of the internal launch code of Java checks if the main class is a subclass of `javafx.application.Application`. If it is, then it launches the JavaFX platform to run the app. This is what lets JavaFX applications omit the main method. However, if the main class is a subclass of `Application`, a check is performed to see if the `javafx.graphics` module is in the _boot_ module layer. So, the proper fix is to make sure the JavaFX modules are resolved and loaded into named modules. But a workaround is to use this answer's approach, which means the check is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from Venkata Raju brought me already half the way with Eclipse (2019-03 with Java 11):

> VM argumments: -> Provide this value `--module-path /<path>/javafx-sdk-11/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls`

In addition, I made sure to **uncheck** "Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when launching with SWT" option in the same panel of the launch configuration.