# JavaFX 16. How to create executable jar using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jar, executable

UPD. [The solution can be found here. Works for both maven and gradle. It is best to use a modular architecture.](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/236)

I am trying to create an executable jar file from [this tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

**I am creating a non-modular Java application like in the tutorial.**

- **Java 16**
- **Gradle 7.1**

**Build.gradle** file structure (Took it from the official **openfx** documentation):

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "16"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.base','javafx.graphics' ]
}

dependencies {
    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:16:win"
    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-base:16:win"
    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:16:win"
}

mainClassName = 'hellofx.Launch'

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    manifest {
        attributes (
            'Main-Class': 'hellofx.Launch'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

[Project structure (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XuA4.jpg)

**Launch.java**

```
package hellofx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Launch extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new AnchorPane());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I can run my application and it works.

`gradlew.bat run`

I can build the jar file.

```
C:\...\fx2000>gradle.bat jar

> Configure project :
Project : => no module-info.java found

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 706ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
```

But if I try to run my jar file, I get this:

```
C:\...\fx2000>java -jar build/libs/fx2000.jar

Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

I understand that the problem lies in the modularity of java. But, I followed the  [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) step by step.

**Manifest file:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: hellofx.Launch
```

[Jar archive structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uOpe.jpg)

[Javafx folder in fx2000.jar archive (folder generated automatically)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqLBk.jpg)

What am I doing wrong? I would like to understand the reason and not find a simple solution.

Comment: it is actually an executable, but you'll need to add JavaFX runtime components, just as the error message indicates

Comment: @Stultuske How exactly do you do this? And why in the documentation I followed, everything starts without this step?

Comment: did you check the "getting started with gluon mobile" part?

Comment: @Stultuske where is the mobile application? I added runtime components in dependencies.

Comment: it's at the start of the tutorial you say you followed

Comment: @Stultuske I am not trying to run this application on a mobile device. [lI am following the path runtime images -> Non-Modular project.](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)

Comment: do you have javafx installed?

Comment: @Stultuske The documentation says:  _If you develop your JavaFX applications using Gradle, you don't have to download the JavaFX SDK. Just specify the modules and the versions you want in the build.gradle file, and the build system will download the required modules, including the native libraries for your platform._. Yes, I tried loading javafx sdk and javafx mods, setting up environment variables. This had no effect.

Comment: it looks like you're not the first to run into issues with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578072/gradle-openjfx11-error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, thanks a lot, it helped me. Add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: if that link provided the answer you needed, it's best to mark it as duplicate