# How to create javaFX jar from a gradle project written in Kotlin

Tags: javafx

So I've found myself in a rabbit hole...
I recently started learning javaFX and have made some apps here and there, well I've now run into a problem on how do I actually build them into a jar?

I use gradle to setup my projects, and run it through gradles application run

basically this video right here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKIMGH0l3Wo

The same guy that made that video also made a video about how to package it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLH-HjiCtaI). Although this doesn't work because I used kotlin to program my apps, and it uses jlink.

I've looked up a bunch of tutorials and guides, but they all talk about using some sort of packager like jlink.

I found a tutorial that builds an artifact which includes the resource folder, which was the closest I found to working, although the application doesn't run (Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application).

So is there a way I can build a jar file? Or did I make a mistake using Kotlin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I manager to find some work arounds, you can use gradle and kotlin, but your main class can't inherit from `javafx.application.Application`. Rather you have your main class call the main function of your main application class, that was a lot of mains, but essentially just this

```
class Main {

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            MainApplication().main(args)
        }
    }

}
```

(The solution I found)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52631238/16655016

Comment: Just to note: Kotlin doesn't require you to create an entire class in order to have a main method. You can have it as a top-level function (e.g. `fun main(args: Array<String>) = MainApplication.main(args)`). But you'll have to change the name of your "main class" when executing the application. For instance, if you put that top-level function in a file named `Main.kt` then (assuming a package of `sample`) the main class is `sample.MainKt`.